# How can i use Sikuli in my python code OR python libraries in Sikuli script

Tags: python, libraries, ui-automation, sikuli

I want to make a python base application in which i have to take decisions in my python .py code file to automate the GUI components using SikuliX.

- How Can I use Sikuli functionality in my python code?
- Can i use python libraries like matplotlib, pandas etc. in Sikuli.script code?

Answer (score 1):

Since Sikuli is written in Java and its "Python" version is not really Python but Jython, you need to seek support for specific Pythonic libraries through Jython documentation and forums. For example have a look at the below links in regards to Jython + matplotlib:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/jython/mailman/message/31496842/
- http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/jython-and-matplotlib-td9782.html

Most generic Python functionality and libraries are supported by Jython but unfortunately not all Python libraries can be used with it.

Having said that, you can have access to all Sikuli features using Java and can easily embed it into Java code.

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)
I want one more thing to ask please.
Can i do something like i can do it in Java, Just import the Sikuli library and play around with Screen object, How can i achieve this in Python code?